# PHP compilation - link to library

Tags: compiling, configuration, php

I am compiling php 5.3.13 on my server. I want to create an autonome php5 folder.
So prefix is:

```
/usr/local/php5
```

In this folder I have a lib folder, where I put all lib needed for php to be executed such as:

```
libk5crypto.so.3
libxml2.so.2
libjpeg.so.62 ....
```

Even if I compile with `--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php5/lib/`, php binary is still looking for the file in `/usr/lib64`.

The only solution I found so far is to manually export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/php5/lib`

I would like the same automatically at compile time. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct linker paths, the *compile* time, and the *run* time.

I find autoconf (`configure`) is rarely set up to do the correct thing with alternate library locations, using `--with-something=` usually does *not* generate the correct linker flags (`-R` or `-Wl,-rpath`). If you only had `.a` libraries it would work, but for `.so` libraries what you need to specify is the `RPATH`:

```
export PHP_RPATHS=/usr/local/php5/lib
./configure [options as required]
```

(In many cases just appending `LDFLAGS` to the `configure` command is used, but PHP's build process is slightly different.)

This effectively adds extra linker search paths to each binary, as if those paths were specified in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or your default linker config (`/etc/ld.so.conf`).
This also takes care of adding `-L/usr/local/php5/lib` to `LDFLAGS` so that the compile-time and run-time use libraries are from the same directory (there's the potential for problems with mismatched versions in different locations, but you don't need to worry here).

Once built, you can check with:

```
 $ objdump -j dynamic -x ./sapi/cli/php | grep RPATH
 RPATH       /usr/local/php5/lib
 $ objdump -j dynamic -x ./libs/libphp5.so | fgrep RPATH
 RPATH       /usr/local/php5/lib
```

Running `ldd` will also confirm which libraries are loaded from where.

What `--with-jpeg-dir` should be really be used for is to point at `/usr/local/` or some top-level directory, the directories `include/`, `lib/`, and possibly others are appended depending on what the compiler/linker needs.

You only need `--with-jpeg-dir` if `configure` cannot find the installation, configure will automatically find it in `/usr/local` and other (possibly platform specific) "standard" places. In your case I think `configure` is finding libjpeg in a standard place, and silently disregarding the directive.

(Also, PHP 5.3.13 is no longer current, I suggest 5.3.21, the current version at this time.)